# MySQL Database fixed (?) query ordering

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database with different picture names which I want to order by name. Problem is that I don't know if I need to do this with PHP or if MySQL can be of any use :)

This is how MySQL orders it, but that of course is wrong - because **-10.jpg** and **-11.jpg** should be at the bottom.

> 106-44XKJ7-1.jpg 
>   106-44XKJ7-10.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-11.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-2.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-3.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-4.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-5.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-6.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-7.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-8.jpg
>   106-44XKJ7-9.jpg

Somewhat further in the table, this is the case;

> 790_49BSBV_2.jpg
>   790_49BSBV_3.jpg
>   790_49BSBV_4.jpg
>   790_49BSBV.jpg

This looks okay, but, as you might have guessed, the one **without** the follow up number (the number after the underscore) should be first, **_2** should be second and so on...

Thanks in advance for your reply! :)

Comment: This is why people use 01.jpg, 02.jpg, etc..

Comment: See if you can order by any other column like an ID column or a date..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common misunderstanding with character fields.  Since 10 and 11 are actually considered characters/text in your field (not numbers), they are indeed being ordered correctly since 10 is "larger" than 1 and "smaller" than 2.

If you want to order them by number, you might try something like parsing the digits from the name, casting them as integers, and then ordering by that.

Something like this in MySQL might work:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE('-', name, 5)), CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE('-', name, 5) + 1), '.jpg', '') as SIGNED)
```

This parses the characters from the beginning and sorts by them.  It then does a secondary sort by locating the second dash in the name and removes everything before it.  It then removes .jpg from that result.  It finally casts it as an integer, which allows it to be sorted correctly.

Alternatively, you can simply add another field to your table (like a DateCreated field) and then sorting is much more straight-forward.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(name, '_', '-'), 1, 5),
    CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(name, '_', '-'), LOCATE('-', REPLACE(name, '_', '-'), 5) + 1), '.jpg', '') as SIGNED)
```

But again, this will give you some possibly wrong sorting.  See my comments below.

Comment: For MySQL - 5.1 atleast the call to `LOCATE` should be `LOCATE('-', name, 5)` i.e. (`string-to-be-searched`,`longer-string`,`position-to-start-search`)

Comment: Yes this works perfectly for the first part. But the OP also has some names with `_` in his second set of examples.

Comment: Indeed, as RedBaron stated. The first part seems to work fine, but when we get to the     _    part, the order by doesnt work ofcourse.

Comment: My 2 suggestions were meant as guidelines for possible directions you could take, not a full-blown answer.  There will NOT be a one-size-fits-all solution to this because you are trying to sort on a notoriously difficult field to sort by (for this very reason) and there will undoubtedly be other naming-conventions not covered in this answer.  As we have suggested, you should probably do your sort on another field - like DateAdded or DateEntered.  However, see my modified answer if you want to continue down this path.